# Different Azure WebRole Endpoint in Development

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

We have two Azure web roles. One for an API and one for an authentication server. In production they will both be on separate hosts so they can both be on port 443. However, in development, we would like to be able to run both at the same time on the same machine. Just for development, we'd like the auth server to run on port 8443 and the API server to run on 443. The problem that we're running into is that we don't see a way to have separate endpoint configurations in development and production. The Endpoint properties for the web role don't allow the endpoints to have different configurations.

The only way we've been able to figure out how to get the system running is to have one of the servers run on 8443 for both development and production which seems like a hack and not scalable from the perspective of development a big system that has lots of endpoints.

Does anyone have a good way to run web roles on different ports in the development environment?

Comment: You can have several Cloud Deployment Projects in the same solution. Perhaps in your case one for development and one for production?

Comment: We are doing the same way as @bzlm is proposing - Separate cloud projects for each environment.

Comment: @GauravMantri I've converted the comment to an answer now that you've second-opinionated it. :) Did you ever have the problems I described in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use separate Windows Azure Cloud Service Projects (`.ccproj`s) to achieve this.** You can use one `ccproj` for the emulated F5 cloud and one `ccproj` for Windows Azure.

These `ccproj`s can either both be in the same solution file, or in separate solution files. When `cspack`ing or F5ing, you still have to choose which `ccproj` to use. For the same solution file approach, just add a new `ccproj` using the Visual Studio tooling.

I've had issues with multiple `ccproj`s in the same solution file, where NuGet packages (most notably the Azure Caching suite) assumed there was only one `ccproj` in the solution and either hence tried to add configuration settings to those role configurations *only*, or just outright crashed. So if you have strange issues of this kind, I'd go for the separate solution files approach.

Comment: We didn't have issues with Nuget as such primarily because we never did package upgrades through Nuget UI. We are always doing it via Package Manager Console. The thing that worries us is keeping config settings in sync across various environments. But other than that, this works like a charm.

Comment: The issues weren't because of the NuGet GUI, or even NuGet itself. The issues were the installation scripts for the Azure Caching suite of packages, which expected at most one CCProj in the solution when adding/removing Azure Caching configuration settings to Role and Endpoint configurations. @GauravMantri

Comment: Thanks. This is a great idea. We have a bunch of projects in the solution and have been able to manage the nuget issues.

Comment: This seems like the best approach. However, be aware that when debugging (F5 in Visual Studio), the cloud services will have different IP's 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, and so on. So far, I haven't found a way to assign an IP to a cloud service. I'm just crossing my fingers hoping that they won't swap (which means I'll have to update configuration).